# Allocation of images to a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code Ive written for placing images in a sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next

    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Call schedules
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub schedules()
    Worksheets("Picture").Activate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim myObj
    Dim Foto
    Set myObj = ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects

    For Each Foto In myObj
        If Left(Foto.Name, 7) = "Picture" Then
            Foto.Select
            Foto.Delete
        End If
    Next
    
    Dim CommodityName1 As String, CommodityName2 As String, T1 As String, T2 As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
        
    l = 0
    j = 0
    
    For i = 2 To 200
        myDir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ESTIMATING SHEETS\test\rebar shapes" & "\"
        CommodityName1 = Range("A" & i)
        T1 = ".png"

        On Error GoTo errormessage:
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=myDir & CommodityName1 & T1, _
          linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=230, Top:=j, Width:=140, Height:=80

errormessage:
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            Exit Sub
            MsgBox "File does not exist." & vbCrLf & "Check the name of the rebar!"
            Range("A" & i).Value = ""
            Range("C10").Value = ""
        End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        i = i + 11
        j = j + 190
        l = l + 1

        If l = 4 Then
            j = j - 20
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            l = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is after the first iteration starts to displace images incorrectly

[image: excel image]

Ive tried using the below code to counteract it but its no good.

```
If l = 4 Then
    j = j - 20
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    l = 0
```

So is there a way to place images in an exact cell position? That way I can run the loop and it wont be off centre

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range.Top` and `Range.Left` to get the top left position of a cell. And you can use that to position your shapes.

So if you have a cell eg E5 and you want to position your picture/object to that cell you can do that like

```
Dim CellToPutTheObject As Range
Set CellToPutTheObject = Range("E5")

With Shapes(1)
    .Top = CellToPutTheObject.Top
    .Left = CellToPutTheObject.Left
End With
```

So now the top left of the `Shape(1)` will be the top left of cell E5.

You can also use

```
.Width = CellToPutTheObject.Width
.Height = CellToPutTheObject.Height
```

to make the width and height to fit the width and height of the cell.

Comment: So how do I replace the below

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=myDir & CommodityName1 & T1, _
     linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=230, Top:=j, Width:=140, 
     Height:=80

With your code

Dim CellToPutTheObject As Range
Set CellToPutTheObject = Range("E5")

With Shapes(1)
    .Top = CellToPutTheObject.Top
    .Left = CellToPutTheObject.Left
End With

Ive tried changing Left:=230 with .Left = CellToPutTheObject.Left but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @tech No this is just an example how to do it. You need to set `CellToPutTheObject` to the cell you want to locate your shape and use the dimensions `CellToPutTheObject.Top` and `CellToPutTheObject.Left`  as `Top:=CellToPutTheObject.Top` in your  `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture`.

Comment: Appreciate the input but I kinda need to understand the syntax so I can replace . The Shapes.Addpicture line in my current code finds the Filename of the shape in the directory provided. If I just say ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture it wont know wherefrom to add the picture. Your suggestion sounds good, just how do I integrate with the line that adds shapes from the file directory?

Answer (score 0):

I Just rewrote it. Found something better

```
    Sub schedulemacro()
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim data As Worksheet, Picture As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    Set data = Sheets("Data")
    Set Picture = Sheets("Picture")
    j = 13
    
    k = WorksheetFunction.CountA(data.Range("b:b"))
    
     Range("A1:G12").Select
     Selection.copy
    
    For i = 1 To k

    Picture.Range("a" & j).Select
     
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
    
    j = j + 12
    Next i
    
    j = 1
    
    For i = 1 To k
    
    Picture.Cells(j, 1) = data.Range("A" & i)
    
    j = j + 12
    
    Next i
    
    Call GetPic
 
    End Sub
    Sub GetPic()
    Dim fNameAndPath As String
    Dim img As Object
    Dim CommodityName1 As String, T1 As String
    Dim myDir As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Worksheets("Picture").Activate
    Dim shape As Excel.shape
    Dim datarangeb As Range
    Dim numberofcells As Integer
    
    Set datarangeb = Sheets("Data").Range("b:b")
    
    numberofcells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(datarangeb)
    numberofcells = numberofcells * 12 + 1
    
    For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            shape.Delete
    Next
    
    
    j = 7
    
    For i = 2 To numberofcells
    
    myDir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ESTIMATING SHEETS\test\rebar shapes" & "\"
    CommodityName1 = Range("a" & i)
    T1 = ".png"
    
    fNameAndPath = myDir & CommodityName1 & T1
    
    On Error GoTo errormessage:
    
        Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
        On Error GoTo errormessage:
        With img
           'Move and Resize Image
           .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
           .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Left
           .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Top
           .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & i).Width
           .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & j).Height
    errormessage:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    Exit Sub
    MsgBox "File does not exist." & vbCrLf & "Check the name of the rebar!"
    End If
           
        End With
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    i = i + 11
     j = j + 12
    Next i
    
    i = i - 1
    
    End Sub
```